# EF Core : one-to-many query with a keyless view as parent source

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a view as parent of a child table, and I need to efficiently query its values in EF Core 7.0, but it throws an error due to missing key on view.

Is there any way to code this query apart from raw SQL?

Switching the parent view into a table is not an option due to complexity of the real-world scenario.

Using a simplified model I can reproduce the issue as follows:

```cs
using(var db = new Entities.TmpContext())
{
    // this code successfully loads the model:
    var modelFromParentTable = db.TmpParents
        .Select(x => new ParentModel
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Children = db.TmpChildren
                        .Where(y => y.Parent == x.Id)
                        .Select(y => new ChildModel
                                    { Name = y.Name })
                        .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

// this code fails due to keyless view:
// Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection 
// since either parent or the subquery doesn't project 
// necessary information required to uniquely identify it and 
// correctly generate results on the client side. This can 
// happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type

var modelFromView = db.VwTmpParents
    .Select(x => new ParentModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Children = db.TmpChildren
                    .Where(y => y.Parent == x.Id)
                    .Select(y => new ChildModel
                                    { Name = y.Name })
                    .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

The models:

```cs
public class ParentModel 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel 
{
    int Parent { get; set; }
    string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

The database objects: a parent table `tmpParent`, a child table `tmpChild` and a view `VwTmpParent` encapsulating parent table

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmpParent]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tmp] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmpChild]
(
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Parent] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tmpChild] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Guid] ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tmpChild] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tmpChild_Guid] DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Guid]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VwTmpParent]
AS
    SELECT Id, Name, GETDATE() AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.tmpParent
GO
```

Populate tables:

```sql
INSERT INTO tmpParent(Id) VALUES (1), (2)

INSERT INTO tmpChild (Parent, Name) 
VALUES (1, 'First parent first child'),
        (1, 'First parent second child'),
        (2, 'Second parent first child')
```

Comment: 1) Try `AsSplitQuery`, it has different Eager Loading technique. 2) How about joining `db.VwTmpParents` to `db.TmpParents` and get fields from `db.TmpParents`?